# iframe app not getting a user id even though logged in

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, embed

I am currently building a flash game, and I've created an iframe app for that

Now the html is in the index file, as well as the php script that handles the requests from the flash object.

The problem is that when the user opens my app, he sees the flash object and I get a user id echoed, but whenever the flash object sends a request to index.php (the same file where the whole html and the flash embed is), I don't get a user id (I'm using the function `getUser()`, should be fine, right?).

I don't know why I couldn't find any similar questions, might just be me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flash application doesn't sent `signed_request` to your php script (and probably any other session identifier too, if any), so you're not able to get the desired info.

You should add `signed_request` (and/or session identifier) parameter to request issuing to your php script...

You can pass `signed_request` to flash via `flashvars` on initialization or via call to JavaScript which will provide this data to flash so it can be passed with every request from flash to server...

Another option is to use Facebook JavaScript SDK which will set `cookie` with name `fbsr_APPID` which will contain `signed_request` so it may be accessed from flash.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that i should POST the signed_request parameter everytime my flash object sends a request, but how do i pass it then to the flash after the initialization? To get a response from the server (the signed_request), i need to send a request, to send a request i need the signed_request parameter, looks like a vicious circle :) And the js can't read POST parameters. Did you mean i should use the js sdk? Or i should assemble it by myself?

Comment: You can use any server side language to pass `signed_request` from canvas (your canvas URL loaded before and already have this data) to flash, just use it in output of your canvas. A bit later I can add a sample (phone isn't great way for typing code)

Comment: Ok, so i just insert a hidden input, its value will be the `signed_request` parameter, and then just send it to the flash object via javascript. Thank you.